# Type hinting callback functions

Tags: python, python-typing

I am currently writing a system using events and event listeners and am running into a problem correctly typing the function signatures of the listeners. The relevant part of the program looks similar to

```py
from typing import Hashable, Callable
from collections import defaultdict

class System:
    def __init__(self):
        self.event_listeners = defaultdict(list)

    def add_event_listener(self, event: Hashable, listener: Callable):
        self.event_listeners[event].append(listener)

    def emit_event(self, event: Hashable, *args, **kwargs):
        for listener in self.event_listeners[event]:
            listener(self, *args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

In addition to the instance of `System` itself, event related information can be passed to the event listeners as further arguments and the type of information (number and types of arguments) is dependent on the specific event.

Is there a way to type the `defaultdict` instance and the function `add_event_listener` to reflect that for every event there is a specific function signature `Callable[[System, ...], object]`, that is expected? I thought about how this can be achieved using `ParamSpec`'s but have not found a solution so far.

Comment: missing `self` parameter for constrctor method

Comment: How specific do you want to be? You could make `add_event_listener` generic, for example, to capture the type of `event` and (potentially) use that specify a specific type for `listener`. (Not entirely sure it's possible; you would need some sort of type-level mapping that evaluates to a type.)

Comment: Your question content and code content are much more complicated than the title suggests. Therefore it's not immediately clear what your concrete problem is. You post also seems to have an unfortunate structure containing irrelevant information (But maybe I'm just sleep deprived)

Answer (score 2):

Give [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) a shot.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Hashable, Protocol
from collections import defaultdict


class EventListener(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, system: System, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        ...


class System:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.event_listeners: defaultdict[Hashable, list[EventListener]] = defaultdict(
            list
        )

    def add_event_listener(self, event: Hashable, listener: EventListener) -> None:
        self.event_listeners[event].append(listener)

    def emit_event(self, event: Hashable, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        for listener in self.event_listeners[event]:
            listener(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the question in your title `Type hinting callback functions`

Use `Callable` (`from typing import Callable`).

###### Structure:

`Callable[[<PARAMETER TYPES>], <RETURN TYPE>]`

###### Examples

```
def call(callback: Callable[[], int]) -> int:
  return callback()

def get1():
  return 1

def getA():
  return 'A'

call(get1) # ok
call(getA) # not ok
```

- `def foo(): pass` has type `Callable[[], None]`
- `def foo(): return 1` has type `Callable[[], int]`
- `def foo(): return '1'` has type `Callable[[], str]`
- `def foo(a: int): return '1'` has type `Callable[[int], str]`
- `def foo(a: int, b: str): return '1'` has type `Callable[[int, str], str]`